# クリップされたビューポートオブジェクトを取得する方法について

Tags: ijcad

現在、IJCAD 2022で.NET API(C#)を使用して開発を行っています。

クリップされたビューポートをEditorクラスのGetEntity()メソッドで選択すると、Viewport型ではなくPolyline型で入ってきます。　
　PolylineではなくViewportオブジェクトを取得したいのですが、方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

以下はサンプルコードです。

```
[CommandMethod("SAMPLE_VIEWPORT", CommandFlags.NoTileMode)]
        public void SAMPLE_VIEWPORT() {
            var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            var db = doc.Database;
            var ed = doc.Editor;

            var opt = new PromptEntityOptions("\nビューポートを選択:");
            opt.AllowNone = false;
            var selRes = ed.GetEntity(opt);
            if (selRes.Status != PromptStatus.OK) return;

            using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) {
                var dbObj = tr.GetObject(selRes.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
            }
        }
```

[image: 画像]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PolylineではなくViewportオブジェクトを取得したいのですが、方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

(2022/7/20 追記)
取得したポリラインオブジェクトに対して、LayoutManager.GetNonRectangularViewportIdFromClipId(ObjectId clipId)メソッドを実行することでビューポートのオブジェクトIDを取得することが可能です。

または、取得したポリラインオブジェクトに対して、DBObject.GetPersistentReactorIds()メソッドを実行することでクリップされたビューポートのオブジェクトIDを取得することができるようです。